# concurrent http request to independent web services

Tags: java, concurrency

i'm trying to find a simple way to send http request concurrently to diferent web services. each request is completely independent of each other.

currently, my implementation look like this ( just a simplification, don't pay attention to design )

let's say a i have a List queries;

```
public class Service { 

       private List<HttpClient> httpClients; // one for each web service

       public List<QueryResult> doQueries(List<Query> queries) { 

               ExecutorService service = Executors.... ; 
               List<Callable<QueryResult>> .... ; 

               for ( Query q : queries ) { 
                          Future<> .....
               }

               service.invokeAll(...) ; 

                ***// what should i do from here ? 
                // how should i wait all those tasks to finish ?*** 


       }
}
```

my question is specifically that. 
how do i wait ?

Comment: Please share the complete code. Where are you collecting `Future` after submitting the requests to `ExecutorService`?

Comment: hi @akhil_mittal. that's my question, how do i proceed from that code ? how do i collect every thread result ?

Comment: [`Fork and Join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) ?

Comment: Also which version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to create a list of `Callable` and each callable will return result of type `QueryResult` as clear from `List<Callable<QueryResult>>`. You will get `Future` after submitting them to `ExecutorService`. So use code in this way:

```
List<Future<QueryResult >> futures = executorService.invokeAll(callables);
for(Future<QueryResult> future : futures){
    System.out.println("future.get = " + future.get());
}
executorService.shutdown();
```

If you want to set some maximum time to wait for result you can use `awaitTermination` method as well. IMO `ExecutorCompletionService` is more suited for your requirements and you can read about it in my article at [dzone](http://java.dzone.com/articles/executorservice-vs).

Comment: seems to be the answer i was looking for.   how could i migrate that code to guava listeningfuture ?

Comment: if you use invokeAll doesn't that means no waiting during the loop on futures ?

Comment: @bayou.io this is what i got from javadoc: "Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete. Future.isDone() is true for each element of the returned list. Note that a completed task could have terminated either normally or by throwing an exception. "  doesn't that means that when i go for the futures loop ( collecting them) they are all complete ?

Comment: `Method submit extends base method Executor.execute(java.lang.Runnable) by creating and returning a Future that can be used to cancel execution and/or wait for completion. Methods invokeAny and invokeAll perform the most commonly useful forms of bulk execution, executing a collection of tasks and then waiting for at least one, or all, to complete. (Class ExecutorCompletionService can be used to write customized variants of these methods.)`

I hope it clears the doubt of all :)

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 choices:

execute each request on a separate thread. Since each thread consumes a lot of memory, you can get OutOfMemoreError if >100 requests run in parallel.

limit the number of threads as akhil_mittal suggested. The number of concurrent requests will be also limited.

Use an async io library, e.g. [nio2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/package-summary.html). They allow thousands of simultaneous requests with moderate memory consumption.

Comment: yes, i ended up using the first option. i used ExecutorService and invokeAll   . i couldn't find a better way to do it.